# Rock Paper Scissors with scores and save file

Tags: python, game, python-2.x, rock-paper-scissors

I've implemented the classic game Rock Paper Scissors with scores, and a save file implementation. I'm looking particularly for ways to get rid of all the `self.`'s. Is there anything I should add, remove, or change. Are there any bugs? Anything else?

```
#Programmer: 
import random as ran
import shelve

class Score(object):
    """Place where all scores are stored for save document"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Makes all variables set to 0"""
        self.rounds = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.wins = 0
        self.draws = 0
        self.game_wins = 0
        self.game_losses = 0
        self.total_rounds = 0
        self.total_games = 0
        self.round_wins = 0
        self.round_losses = 0
        self.round_draws = 0

    def reset(self):
        """Resets the scores for next game"""
        self.wins = 0
        self.draws = 0
        self.losses = 0

    def tally(self):
        """Adds the score to stats"""
        self.total_rounds += self.rounds
        self.total_games += 1
        self.round_wins += self.wins
        self.round_losses += self.losses
        self.round_draws += self.draws

    def stats(self):
        """Prints the stats"""
        print ('\n\n+++++++++++++++++++++-=Stats=-+++++++++++++++++++')
        print ('=================================================')
        print ('|--           --|--   Rounds  --|--   Games   --|')
        print ('|--   Wins    --|--     %s     --|--     %s     --|')    %(self.round_wins, self.game_wins)
        print ('|--   Losses  --|--     %s     --|--     %s     --|')    %(self.round_losses, self.game_losses)
        print ('|--   Draws   --|--     %s     --|--    N/A    --|')    %(self.round_draws)
        print ('|--   Played  --|--     %s     --|--     %s     --|\n\n')%(self.total_rounds, self.total_games)

    def final(self):
        """Prints final score of the game just played"""
        print ('\n\n+++++++++++Final Score++++++++++')
        print ('================================')
        print ('|--   Wins    --|--    %s     --|')    %(self.wins)
        print ('|--   Losses  --|--    %s     --|')    %(self.losses)
        print ('|--   Draws   --|--    %s     --|')    %(self.draws)
        print ('|--   Rounds  --|--    %s     --|\n\n')    %(self.rounds)


def custom_input(question, choices):
    """A custom loop that checks to see if choices is valid"""
    response = raw_input(question).lower()
    while response not in choices:
        print ("Correct inputs: ")
        for c in choices:
            print(c)
        response = raw_input(question).lower()
    return response


class Game(object):
    """Main game"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Starts the program here."""
        try:                                    
            f = shelve.open("RPS_save.dat")     
            statistics = f["statistics"]        
            self.score = statistics[0]          
            f.close()
        except:
            self.score = Score()
            f = shelve.open("RPS_save.dat")
            statistics = [self.score]
            f["statistics"] = statistics
            f.sync()
            f.close()
        self.Continue = None
        self.game = None
        self.plays = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
        self.games = ['1', '3', '5']
        self.modes = ['pvc', 'cvc']
        self.p1win = [('rock' + 'scissors'), ('paper' + 'rock'), ('scissors' + 'paper')]
        self.menu = [('stats'), ('play'), ('quit')]
        while self.Continue is None:
            self.Continue = raw_input("Welcome to the greatest, mind blowing, challenge of all "
                    "time.\n   - Rock, Paper, Scissors! \nMany have tried and many have"
                    " FAILED... \nThis will be a test between the human mind and"
                    " my AI.\nPress \"enter\" when you believe your ready for this "
                    "challenge.\n")
        print "Good Luck... Human."
        while True:
            self.game = custom_input("Would you like to play, look at stats, or quit?\n", self.menu)
            if self.game == "play":
                self.rounds = custom_input("How many rounds would you like? \n", self.games)
                self.play_game()
                self.score.tally()
                self.score.final()
                self.score.reset()
                f = shelve.open("RPS_save.dat")
                statistics = [self.score]
                f["statistics"] = statistics
                f.sync()
                f.close()
            elif self.game == "stats":
                self.score.stats()
            if self.game == "quit":
                break


    def play_game(self):
        """This is where most of the game takes place"""
        while self.score.rounds != int(self.rounds):
            self.score.rounds += 1
            self.user_choice = custom_input("What is your choice, human! \n  ",self.plays)
            self.computer_choice = self.computer_choice_gen()
            print "\nComputer choice is %s"    %(self.computer_choice)
            result = self.evaluate()
            if result == "win":
                print "%s beats %s! The human wins this round.\n\n"   %(self.user_choice.capitalize(), self.computer_choice)
                self.score.wins += 1
            elif result == "loss":
                print "%s beats %s! Hahaha! You lost this round!\n\n" %(self.computer_choice.capitalize(), self.user_choice)
                self.score.losses += 1
            else:
                print "I knew you were going to pick %s!\n\n"        %(self.user_choice.capitalize())
                self.score.draws += 1
        self.finals()

    def finals(self):
        """Adds win /losses to scores"""
        if self.score.wins > self.score.losses:
            self.score.game_wins += 1
            print "Looks like humans are still dominant in this time. You won the Game!"
        else:
            self.score.game_losses += 1
            print "Humans are no match for my AI."

    def computer_choice_gen(self):
        """Generates computer choice"""
        return ran.choice(self.plays)

    ##def computer_choice():
    ##    chance = ran.randint(0, 99)
    ##    if chance > 66:
    ##        return "rock"
    ##    elif chance < 33:
    ##        return "paper"
    ##    else:
    ##        return "scissors"

    def evaluate(self):
        """Determines whether game is a win loss or draw"""
        if self.user_choice + self.computer_choice in self.p1win:
            return "win"
        elif self.user_choice == self.computer_choice:
            return "draw"
        else:
            return "loss"


Game()
```

Comment: Re-tagged it to [python-2.7], as the OP commented on an answer that this was actually python-2.4, but we don't have that tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't `import random as ran`! What does this save you? 3 characters, and causes headaches for anyone who misses or forgets that you've done this. You only even call it once, so aliasing it takes *more* characters since you need to add `as ran` just to avoid writing `dom` once.

`Score` is actually a pretty good way of arranging a class, you have some useful methods for it. Though a name like `Scoreboard` or `Scorecard` might be more appropriate to indicate it holds a series of scores. Also, given the nature of your class it could be easier to have it inherit from `dict`. That way all your attributes can be keys instead. This makes it easier to loop over setting keys and allows you to access functions like `.keys()` and `.values()`. Take a look at how your `__init__` can look with this:

```
class Score(dict):
    """Place where all scores are stored for save document"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Makes all variables set to 0"""
        for key in ("rounds", "losses", "wins", "draws", "game_wins",
                    "game_losses", "total_rounds", "total_games",
                    "round_wins", "round_losses", "round_draws"):
            self[key] = 0
```

You can do a similar thing with `reset` too. Of course this affects how you access `self.scores`, instead of dot syntax you'll access it with a key.
ie. `self.score['rounds']` instead of `self.score.rounds`.

Instead of using the `%` syntax for string formatting you should use `str.format` as that's the new method. It also makes tables easier because you can specify the spacing and get messages to be centered with the syntax it allows. For example this line:

```
    print ('|--   Wins    --|--     %s     --|--     %s     --|')    %(self.round_wins, self.game_wins)
```

could be rewritten as:

```
    print ('|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|').format("Wins", self.round_wins, self.game_wins)
    # |--   Wins    --|--     6      --|--     12     --|
```

To explain, the values are substituted in wherever there's `{}` brackets. The colon separates an index value(which we haven't used) from formatting info. The `^` indicates to center the text and then the number tells Python how many spaces it should take up as a minimum. The beauty of this format is that you can reuse the same string to format for every line and just pass the relevant values:

```
def stats(self):
    """Prints the stats"""
    print ('\n\n+++++++++++++++++++++-=Stats=-+++++++++++++++++++')
    print ('=================================================')
    print ('|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|').format("", "Rounds", "Games")
    print ('|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|').format("Wins", self.round_wins, self.game_wins)
    print ('|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|').format("Losses", self.round_losses, self.game_losses)
    print ('|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|').format("Draws", self.round_draws, "N/A")
    print ('|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|').format("Played", self.total_rounds, self.total_games)
    print ('\n')
```

Also, are you aware of `__str__`? It's a magic method, if you were to change the name of `stats` to `__str__` and returned the values instead of printing them then you could make this table be the string representation of your object. This is how it would need to look:

```
def __str__(self):
    """Table of all stats"""

    return ('\n\n+++++++++++++++++++++-=Stats=-+++++++++++++++++++\n'
            '=================================================\n'
            '|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|\n'.format("", "Rounds", "Games")
            '|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|\n'.format("Wins", self.round_wins, self.game_wins)
            '|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|\n'.format("Losses", self.round_losses, self.game_losses)
            '|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|\n'.format("Draws", self.round_draws, "N/A")
            '|--{:^11}--|--{:^12}--|--{:^12}--|\n'.format("Played", self.total_rounds, self.total_games)
            '\n\n')
```

The main change is returning instead of printing. But also manually adding newlines since it's not a print statement. Also you don't need to explicitly concatenate them. String literals are implicitly concatenated when placed next to each other without an operator or comma separator:

```
>>> "ban" "ana"
'banana'
```

It's good to see an input wrapper function, though I don't know why it's separated out from `Game`, especially when `Game` calls on it. You should include it. You can also print your `choices` easier using `str.join`. It will take an iterable of strings and then join all the strings contained in it, with a string separating values. ie. `'\n'.join(choices)` will put a newline character between each choice, which is the same as your `for` loop.

Ethan is correct that your `__init__` does too much. It should be for initialising. Creating values and storing them in the proper form. Everything after `self.menu` should be in a `run` function.

Also, some of your attributes are constants that should be at the class level. `plays`, `games`, `menu` and `p1win` are all unchanged by `__init__`, so they should just be defined in `Game` itself. Also since they're constants they should be in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE naming format, and they should be tuples, not lists. Tuples are immutable and indicate a constant value much clearer.

```
class Game(object):
    """Main game"""

    PLAYS = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    GAMES = ('1', '3', '5')
    MODES = ('pvc', 'cvc')
    P1WIN = ('rock' + 'scissors', 'paper' + 'rock', 'scissors' + 'paper')
    MENU = ('stats', 'play', 'quit')
```

You can access these either with `self.PLAYS` or `Game.Plays`, but I think the latter is clearer about it being a class attribute. At that, I'd point out that `MODES` isn't implemented and you could use better names. `PLAYS` should be someting like `MOVES`. `GAMES` should be `ROUNDS` or `ROUND_OPTIONS` maybe?

Also I don't see the point of your `Continue` at all, it's used as a flag `while self.Continue is None`, but then `raw_input` immediately unsets that because any result of it will not be `None`? Just remove it, having the `raw_input` by itself is enough. Likewise, though you actually do use `self.game` you don't need to initialise it as none. It doesn't even need to be an attribute, as it's only used in one function.

You don't need to temporarily assign `statistics` either, you can do this:

```
        statistics = f["statistics"]        
        self.score = statistics[0]
```

in one line:

```
        self.score = f['statistics'][0]
```

You could do a similar thing when writing to it later:

```
            f["statistics"] = [self.score]
```

Back to your long `raw_input`, it's way too long a string. Just print line by line and then wrap the final line in `raw_input`. All your newline characters in the middle of the string are awkward to read.

Just turn `self.rounds` into an `int` once instead of repeatedly calling it like this. There's no real reason to keep it a string after the user has entered it.

Your method of evaluating wins and losses is odd. Concatenated strings that indicate the player's victory are counter intuitive. You could instead have a dictionary of values doing a similar thing:

```
WIN_CONDITIONS = {
    "rock": "scissors",
    "scissors": "paper",
    "paper": "rock",
    }
```

This would make your test look like this:

```
    if Game.WIN_CONDITIONS[self.user_choice] == self.computer_choice:
        return "win"
```

It may be more verbose but it indicates the idea clearer and key value pairs are more understood than concatenated strings.

Comment: Wow, you always have some of the best reviews. Every time post a program I always look for your answers because they are always very detailed and helpful.

Comment: Can you review my new version please? [new](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110586/rockpaperscissorsv2-follow-up-advanced)

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Hey I just got time to take a look. There was a lot less to say this time (which is a good thing!) but I hope it's still helpful.

Answer (score 5):

## Proper error catching

Never, ever have an empty `except` clause like the following:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

With an empty `except` clause, *any* error that occurs in the `try` block will be caught by the `except` clause. This includes errors that aren't intended to be caught, like a `SystemError`, where something goes wrong internally.

The proper way to specify what error you want to catch would be to write your `except` clause like this:

```
except ExceptionType:
    ...
```

---

## Properly opening files

The generally accepted method for opening files in Python is to use a contest manager, as seen below. If you use a context manager, the file is closed implicitly, and you can guarantee that the file is closed properly if the program unexpectedly exits:

```
with open("path/to/my/file.dat", "mode") as my_file:
    ...
```

---

## OOP Design

It feels like you're not using object-oriented-programming correctly, as your `__init__` methods seem to be doing *way* too much. As the name implies, the magic method `__init__` should only be used for class initialization, and nothing else. Right now, you're treating the `__init__` method like the *"main method"* of your class.

The best way that I can think of would be to do two things:

1. Use a global state. I wouldn't highly recommend this, but if the program is small and trivial enough, then it's probably okay.
2. Represent items like a `Scissor`, or a `Rock` with objects.

---

## Nitpicks

- Classes in Python 3.x are implicitly new-style, and don't need to explicitly inherit from `object`. This means they can be declared in a fashion like this:

  ```
  class MyClass:
      ...
  ```
- Functions like `stats()` or `final()` should probably return a string, rather than explicitly printing one.

Comment: This is python 2.4 as it was an assignment meant for class. I've already turned in the assignment earlier, so I guess I can go ahead and change it to a 3.x program.

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes Yeah, I'd highly recommend that you change to 3.5. It's quite better.

Comment: I haven't messed with 3.x that much is there any major differences? I normally use 2.7 as it's similar to my class. I have 2.7, 2.4, and whatever the latest python 3 version is in separate virtual machines

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes There are some significant changes you can [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html), though since 3.0 they've obviously added more.

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes as you are using python2.4 you cannot use `with`. It was [added in 2.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). But then again, you shouldn't be using 2.4 as [there is no support for it since 2004](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0320/)... (Just so you know)

Comment: @JoeWallis Yeah, as I said above though this was originally a class assignment, so it had to be written in 2.4 originally, but now I can change it to a newer version because I have already submitted the assignment a few days ago.

Answer (score 4):

First of all do read the [excellent answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/109862/78136) of SuperBiasedMan, on which I would like to make some additional notes:

- Instead of `self[key] = 0`, you could use `setattr(self, key, 0)`, and keep your existing code like `self.score`
- Another alternative to the win conditions could be to use tuples, instead of string conditions:

  ```
  P1WIN = [('rock', 'scissors'), ('paper', 'rock') , ('scissors', 'paper')] 
  ...

  if (self.user_choice, self.computer_choice) in self.p1win:
      return "win"
  ```

### Extend `Score`

I would change the `Score` class to have all the counters as internal variables, and add methods to change the score. You could then do a `self.score.add_win()` which would correctly update current wins, round wins and total.

This would also eliminate a bug in your current code. Within `play_game` you do `self.score.wins += 1`, and just after that in `tally` you add the accumulated value of wins & co in `self.round_wins += self.wins`. Bug! The wins accumulate really fast for winning rounds...

You could also have a method, in addition to those pretty print methods, which returned tuple's of the scores, i.e. three tuples for game, round and total, where each tuple had wins, losses and draws. This would allow code outside of score to see the score, but not manipulate besides the ordinary methods.

You could also allow for score to handle its own saving and loading, without too much fuzz.

Comment: I've posted an [update](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110586/rockpaperscissorsv2-follow-up-advanced) to this program. I would like to see your review on it. :)